# tips about creating VisualStudio LanguageService (for languages similar to java)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, add-in

I need to create in very short period of time proof of concept for Visual Studio Language Service supporting "Java-like" languages.

I would like to ask you about experience with creating VisualStudio LanguageServices or similar addins. Where I should prepare for really hard battle and what is easier to implement than it appears to be ?

Which stupid mistakes should I try avoid in first place, if I don't have to much time?